# PHP Delete Function not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, error-handling, sql-delete

Have had a look around but still struggling like no tomorrow. Just trying to get a delete button working. But its made complicated because the delete function is not completed on the one file.

Users are currently on the crud/view.php file

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid']))

$uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];

require_once('connect.php');

$ReadSql = "SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE users_id=$uid ORDER BY Name";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $ReadSql);

?>
```

I have a few functions but my delete button is:

```
<td> <input type="button" onClick="deleteme(<?php echo $r['u_uid']; ?>)" name="Delete" value="Delete"></td>
```

Followed by:

```
function deleteme(delid) {
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?")){
window.location.href='delete.php?del_id='+delid;
 }
 }
```

Leading to a crud/delete.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])){

 require_once('connect.php');

 $select = "DELETE from contact where id='".$_GET['del_id']."'";
 $query = mysqli_query($connection, $select) or die($select);
 }else {

 print_r($_GET['del_id']) 
 ?>
```

I think you can have the delete function on just the view.php and get rid of the delete.php. But I'm not sure what to do.

Many thanks!

Comment: is the id a string or int? If it's an int, then I would remove the single quotes. Ultimately, you should look into prepared statements once you get this working.

Comment: Ah id is an int. Which single quotes are you referring to?

Comment: ```$select = "DELETE from contact where id='".$_GET['del_id']."'"; ``` The id=''

Comment: wide open to SQL injection attacks, dont use this code

Comment: I just want it to woooork man :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the variables really contain something that you expect it to have, does the `u_uid` was really set, try printing out your delete query to make sure that it builds a valid SQL statement.

Or you can try enclosing your table fields with back-ticks, like you did on your select statement.

It is very advisable also to use prepared statements to make your script more secured.